# Как в flask_sqlalchemy указать путь до таблице

Tags: python, flask

Написал

```
class KeyValueStorage(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'data.key_value_storage'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Выдал

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) ОШИБКА: 
>   отношение "data.key_value_storage" не существует

Зачем он путь в двойные кавычки завернул? И как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Он" их завернул в двойные кавычки для того, чтобы вывести текст ошибки в соответствии с нормами русского языка. Это не надо обходить. В вашем случае, если вы используете схемы в БД, надо уведомить ORM об этом:

```
class KeyValueStorage(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'key_value_storage'
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'data'}
```